# Flutter build faied with firebase package

Tags: flutter, firebase

I working on Mac mini M1 2020.

I got error when build my app (by run `flutter run` command):

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
```

Running pod install...                                             517ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_app_badger` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_app_badger/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_local_notifications` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_local_notifications/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `package_info_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/package_info_plus/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_ios/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `uni_links` from `.symlinks/plugins/uni_links/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `video_player_avfoundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/video_player_avfoundation/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `wakelock` from `.symlinks/plugins/wakelock/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `webview_flutter_wkwebview` from `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter_wkwebview/ios`
[!] No podspec found for `webview_flutter_wkwebview` in `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter_wkwebview/ios`

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:14:in `block in fetch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:993:in `fetch_external_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:972:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:971:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:971:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:970:in `fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:117:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `10.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See
`https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).

Anyone let me know how to solve this?

Thank you so much

Comment: When I run pod install again, it showing:
```Analyzing dependencies
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.15.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] No podspec found for `webview_flutter_wkwebview` in `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter_wkwebview/ios`

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `12.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

1.flutter clean

2.delete /ios/Pods

3.delete /ios/Podfile.lock

4.flutter pub get

5.from inside ios folder: pod install

6.flutter run

Comment: I cannot passed step 5, it's always show error like: https://imgur.com/a/9FDFTbv, can you check?

Comment: I uninstall flutter then re-install again. Now it's working :(